# Custom FORMS_PATH is not working in Oracle forms 11G

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracleforms

I am trying to setup Oracle Forms to deliver 2 forms from 2 different directories. For this I put my forms in following locations

- APP1 : /oracle/weblogic/middleware/as_1/forms_app1
- APP2 : /oracle/weblogic/middleware/as_1/forms_app2

Then set "formsweb.cfg" file to use 2 env files for "app1" and "app2". And in the app1.env file I set "FORMS_PATH" to app1 form location and also for app2.

But When I try to access the forms, I get blank screen. If I put my forms to "/oracle/weblogic/middleware/as_1/forms", it is working.

My formsweb.cfg

```
[app1]
WebUtilArchive=frmwebutil.jar,jacob.jar,icons.jar
WebUtilLogging=off
WebUtilLoggingDetail=normal
WebUtilErrorMode=Alert
WebUtilDispatchMonitorInterval=5
WebUtilTrustInternal=true
WebUtilMaxTransferSize=16384
baseHTML=webutilbase.htm
baseHTMLjpi=webutiljpi.htm
archive=frmall.jar,icons.jar,myicon.jar,ComboBoxComplettion.jar,jacob_new.jar
lookAndFeel=oracle
form=app_login.fmx
envFile=app1.env
userid=finance/finance@app1
heartBeat=31
separateFrame=true
height=100
width=100
background=/forms/java/bg.jpg
codebase=/forms/java
imageBase=codebase
otherparams= repserver_name=Repserver_app1 apps_url=http://10.10.10.10 serverpath=/oracle/weblogic/middleware/as_1/forms_app1
```

And I am using same form name (app_login.fmx) for both "APP1" and "APP2".
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you create the directory forms_app1 and 2 as oracle user? And also for the fmx files? If this is not the case you should set the rights for the directory on 777 and for the fmx files on 666.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a "workingDirectory" option in your formsweb.cfg file.
For the first form he will look at this option and now he probably takes that option from the default-config section which has the main path.